# Converting an Observable<String> to String

Tags: rx-swift

I need to take the string contents of an observable and use them elsewhere in the code

Converting the observable to String

```
let email = userEmail.map{userEmail return userEmail}
```

Cannot convert value of type 'Observable' to expected argument type 'String'

Answer (score 4):

`Observable.map` will wrap the resulting value in an `Observable` again, so that won't work.

What you're asking for isn't possible with just `Observable`. You'll have to subscribe to the value and use it in the subscription block:

```swift
userEmail.subscribe(onNext: { userEmail in
    // Do something with `userEmail`.
})
```

You *could* replace your `Observable<String>` with a `BehaviorRelay<String>`. It remembers the current value, which you can access with `BehaviorRelay.value`.

If changing `Observable<String>` to `BehaviorRelay<String>` is not possible, you could still create a `BehaviorRelay<String?>` and bind `Observable<String>` to it:

```swift
let userEmailRelay = BehaviorRelay<String?>(value: nil) // Needs to have a value from the beginning.
userEmail
    .map(Optional.init) // Change the type from `Observable<String>` to `Observable<String?>` to match the type of `userEmailRelay`.
    .bind(to: userEmailRelay)
```

Alternatively, you might want to start with an empty string, allowing you to use `BehaviorRelay<String>` instead:

```swift
let userEmailRelay = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
userEmail.bind(to: userEmailRelay)
```

Finally, access the latest value:

```swift
let email = userEmailRelay.value
```